# A click function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

my a click jquery function is not working, it just doesn't give any errors at console at all too. 
Here is the link -

```
<a href="#lang" id="language">Edit</a>
```

and here is the click function

```
$('a').click(function() {
 var item = $(this).attr("id");
 alert(item);        
 return false;
});
```

It doesn't popout the alert box, nor it does show me error in console.

Okay, someone asked for more info -

The link is added with jquery, by pressing button, and as id it takes one of the input fields value and inserts it as link with id from input field. There are no duplicate ids, all javascript scripts are located at the end of head tag, and the a click function is located last in  part.

Comment: Need context. The code is fine, it's probably *where* the code is in your page that's the problem.

Comment: Is the code in a DOM ready event handler? If not, no `a` elements will exist at the time it runs.

Comment: Can you tell us where that code is it? In the  `$(document).ready` event? Where?  If the code that binds the `click` is in header, then $('a') will be an empty set, since no 'a' tags have been created yet.

Comment: @Thatsmeeee: Since the link is added dynamically, you have to go about attaching the click handler differently, using either `on()` or `live()`. Please see my answer below.

Comment: Colin, okay, that solves my problem, but now 2nd question -         `var item = $(this).attr("id");        
        $('#language_c').remove(item);` why it doesn't remove the item from #language_c input field? theese two lines are between the a click function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your edit that the `<a>` tag is being inserted dynamically, you'll need to use jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (jQuery version 1.7 and later) or [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method to attach the click handler.

Comment: Colin, okay, that solves my problem, but now 2nd question - `var item = $(this).attr("id"); $('#language_c').remove(item);` why it doesn't remove the item from #language_c input field? theese two lines are between the a click function

Comment: @Thatsmeeee: If this answer was helpful, consider voting it up. If it solved your problem, consider [marking it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Regarding your second issue, `.remove()` takes a selector as an argument, not an id. If you want to remove that particular input field, simply call `$('#language_c').remove();`

Answer (score 0):

This code should work, so I suppose there is some other error *before* this code runs that prevents correct Javascript execution.

Edit: *OR* the DOM is not yet ready when you insert the Javascript code. Then you should use

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
     var item = $(this).attr("id");
     alert(item);        
     return false;
    });​
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you wrapping it on the ready event or after the element has been displayed? If so then it should work;

http://jsfiddle.net/sWeRf/

Comment: Here is how it's for me - http://jsfiddle.net/sWeRf/2/ I have little bit changed the code, but it still almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

Either place this code after the `<a href="#lang" id="language">Edit</a>` on the page, or put it in the head with `$(document).ready(function() { //Place code here. });`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing your JS code with the following (put between the HEAD tags)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a#lang').click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking the document is loaded before applying your JQuery click handler?

e.g.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('a').click(function() {
         var item = $(this).attr("id");
         alert(item);        
         return false;
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using document.ready you can use an anonymous function that does the same thing.

Like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        var item = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(item);        
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the item do this:

```
$('#language_c').remove();
```